# render actionIndex() SQL query so available in other view file in Yii

Tags: yii

I've just started using Yii and i'm just creating my home page, I use two views for this file, index.php and column1.php. I have the following code in my SiteController.php

```
public function actionIndex()
{

// limits query for index page results to 10
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$Criteria->limit = 10;
// renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
// using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
$this->render('index', array(
                'ItemDetails' => ItemDetail::model()->findAll($Criteria),
        ));
}
```

This just recalls the latest 10 records that I want to display on my home page. To access the records in my index.php file i just use

```
<?php foreach($ItemDetails as $ItemDetail):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $ItemDetail->title;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ItemDetail->des;?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

The only hitch is that I need this code outputted to my column1.php view. How do I achieve this?Currently i'm just getting undefined variables or should I just put everything in my index.php view - I'm a little unsure, so would appreciate some guidance

Thanks

Jonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the colum1 is a layout not a view, you can make it by set the layout in the begining of the function actionIndex like this `$this->layout='column1'`
maybe you need a partial render.
[basics view layout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.view#layout)
[layout detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail)
look the blog exemple for render partial

Comment: Hi cherif_b, yes you are right I include the column1 layout inside the index.php view using <?php $this->layout='column1'; ?> inside my index view, which is where i need to be able to return the sql data - any further ideas?